# What limits/colimits are preserved by the Yoneda embedding?

Tags: category-theory

I know that the contravariant Yoneda embedding $X\mapsto \mathcal{C}(-,X)$ preserves all small limits that exist in $\mathcal{C}$. I guess it follows that the covariant Yoneda embedding preserves all colimits.

But what happens if we have a case in which a limit (rather than a colimit) appears in the first argument of hom, i.e we have a functor of the form $\mathcal{C}(\varprojlim X_i,-)$? None of the two cases above apply. Are there cases in which that functor becomes $\varprojlim \mathcal{C}(X_i,-)$ or $\varinjlim \mathcal{C}(X_i,-)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\text{Hom}$ functor preserves limits in *each* argument (in a very strong sense), neither preserves colimits in general.  You should prove this as it's the source of continuity for most other things that are continuous, most notably adjoints. (Because (co)limits in functor categories are computed point-wise, this lifts to the Yoneda embeddings.)

But be a bit careful, $\text{Hom}(-,X)$ is a functor $\mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$, so being continuous means it takes *co*limits in $\mathcal{C}$ to limits in $\mathbf{Set}$.  (Of course, this is equivalent to taking limits in $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ to limits in $\mathbf{Set}$, i.e. continuity.)

Considering a slightly different problem, if we *fix* an $X$ and ask what does it mean for $\text{Hom}(X,-)$ to preserve all *co*limits, you get the notion of a [tiny object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object) assuming $\mathcal{C}$ has all colimits (this situation is the same as the one you were talking about, just in the opposite category).  An object being tiny is an unusual thing, for example, in $\mathbf{Set}$, the only tiny object is the terminal object.  It would be unusual for a cocomplete category to have nothing but tiny objects.  In fact, considering different classes of colimits gives different notions of "smallness".  For example, if $\text{Hom}(X,-)$ preserves all [filtered colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+limit), then $X$ is a [compact or finitely presented object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object).  A [strongly finitely presented object](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n3/8-03abs.html) is one for which that functor preserves all [sifted colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sifted+colimit).  A [connected object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+object) (in an extensive category) is one where that functor preserves coproducts. [A duality relative to a limit doctrine](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/10/20/10-20abs.html) gives some general definitions and results for situations like this.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So in the example I gave, $\mathcal{C}(\varprojlim X_i,-)$ becomes $\varinjlim \mathcal{C}(X_i,-)$ because limits are taken to colimits, right?

Comment: @arturoB No, colimits are taken to limits, not the other way around.

Comment: So there is nothing we can say about this particular example? Is this the whole point?

Comment: @arturoB If your intent is that *all* limits get taken to colimits, then you are saying all objects of $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ are tiny (at least if $\mathcal{C}$ is complete). I'm not aware of any research on categories with such a property. I haven't thought about it much, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are only trivial examples. For example, $\mathcal{C}$ can't have a terminal object because this says that $\text{Hom}(1,1) \cong \emptyset$ which is false.

Comment: I think it's misleading to say continuity of hom functors is the source of continuity of adjoints. Hom functors are way more than continuous: they preserve arbitrary limits, not just small ones. Further, adjoint functors, even between categories that are not locally small, preserve arbitrary Kan extensions - this does not (and cannot) depend on the fact that Hom functors preserve limits.